# C# ? operator syntax

Tags: c#, operators

a simple question:

Is there a syntax for this kind of operation in C#:

- If condition, return the object itself : default value

Like in below example, but I don't want to evaluate the myObject twice (which could be some much more complicated thing like database query):

```
int myVar = (myObject == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)myObject);
```

I know there is syntax for this when checking null (like in below example), but is there for checking any different value, like DBNull.Value in this case?

```
int myVar = Convert.ToInt32(myObject ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No:

```
int myVar = myObject == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)myObject;
```

Is the best you can do. It doesn't evalutate the object twice just because it is mentioned twice.

Or wrap it in a function of course:

```
int myVar = DBObjectToInt(myObject);

public static int DBObjectToInt(object dbObj)
{
  return dbObj == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dbObj;
}
```

Another option is using [`Coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) in your SQL, so you don't even get a DBNull in the first place.

Comment: So you say this doesn't go twice the db-query here: int i =(dt.Compute("MAX( Column )", string.Empty) == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dt.Compute("MAX( Column )", string.Empty));

Comment: I Know I Can store it in a temp variable, but I was hoping that i could do all this in one line of code :)

Comment: Yes, but I assumed `myObject` was the name of a variable. So you would have already done `var myObject = dt.Compute("MAX( Column )", string.Empty);`

Comment: You can using the function `int myVar = DBObjectToInt(dt.Compute("MAX( Column )", string.Empty));`

Comment: Another option is using [`Coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) in your SQL, so you don't even get a `DBNull` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to evaluate the object twice. Evaluate the object, store it in a variable, and do the checks on the resulting variable.

The answer to your question is no, you can't just create your own mini language in C# at whim. There are shortcuts for the most-common operations, but a custom ternary unary operator is not one.

Comment: I Know I Can store it in a temp variable, but I was hoping that i could do all this in one line of code :)